# How to Store Values from HTML Dropdown list to MySQL DB in Flask

Tags: flask

Hi I am using the following code to save the values entered in the below html page to MySQL DB. Added the dropdown list "RequestType" but when selecting the values from "RequestType" and hitting the Submit Button encountering the below error. Placed the codes used in Flask and HTML. Request your help to resolve this issue.

**TypeError: execute() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given**

[Basic html page with three values i.e. name, email and Request Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGV7K.png)

**The Code used in Flask is as below**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL


app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure db
#db = yaml.load(open('db.yaml'))
app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
#app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = 'P@$$w0rd'
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = 'flaskapp'




mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Fetch form data
        userDetails = request.form
        name = userDetails['name']
        email = userDetails['email']
        requesttype = userDetails.get('requesttype')
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users(name, email, requesttype) VALUES(%s, %s, [])", name, email, requesttype)
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return 'Save is Successful'
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**The HTML code is as below.**

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('index') }}">

    Name <input type="text" name="name" />
      <br>

    Email <input type="email" name="email" />
      <br> 
    RequestType <select id="RequestType" name = "RequestType" >
     <option selected value="1">New</option>
     <option value="0">Old</option>
    </select><br>  
    <input type="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: have you tried replacing `VALUES (%s, %s, [])` by `VALUES (%s,%s,%s)`? Do you get the same error? Also, in your python file at `userDetails.get` it says `'requesttype'` but in your html file the name says `'RequestType'`, as far as I know they should match exactly (it's case-sensitive). Finally, as a general question (I'm not expert), why are you using `userDetails.get('requesttype')` instead of `userDetails['requesttype']`? For example, I managed to insert values into MySql without using `get` regardless of whether it is a `select` or an `input`

Comment: Hi Thank You for your reply. have performed the suggested changes but still encountering the same error. Can you please share the code to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work

```
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Fetch form data
        userDetails = request.form
        name = userDetails['name']
        email = userDetails['email']
        requesttype = userDetails['RequestType']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute("""INSERT INTO users (name, email, requesttype) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", (name, email, requesttype))
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        return 'Save is Successful'
     return render_template('index.html')
```

The triple quotation mark will prevent you from any syntax error in MySQL. Also note the added parenthesis at `(name, email, requesttype)`.

Comment: Hi Its Saving without any Error .. but it always save the "New" Value even I select the "Old" from the Dropdown select. Can you please help me on this

Comment: do you get the same error if you delete `"selected"`? I can't reproduce the error in my current computer since I don't have Mysql and python installed here.

Comment: Hi Thank You for your reply, The issue is not with the code.. the issue is with HTML ..have rectified it.. its all good now.. cheers !!

Comment: Hi Mate .. Sorry to bother you again ... as now I can save the values to DB.. my next step is to search the values based on the email and get the values like name and request type  , update them and save it back to the DB.. can you please guide me to do that ... thank you for your help in Advance

Comment: It's bit easier for me if you try something first so that I can help you out starting from what you've tried. Otherwise your request is quite general and I'm not qualified to help

Comment: Hi Mate .. Finally I came up with some thing .. but struck again. I am trying to edit the saved values. And as a first step trying to fetch the records that needs to be edited. Results are displayed as below

Comment: The code to edit is as below    @app.route('/Update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Update():
       # request.method == 'GET':
        # Fetch form data
        user = request.form
        CR_ID = user['CR_ID']
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
     #   result= cur.execute("SELECT CR_ID, name, email  from users where CR_ID = 1")
        result = cur.execute("SELECT CR_ID, name, email, CRType from users where CR_ID = %s",CR_ID)
        RV = cur.fetchall()
        user = RV[0]
        cur.close()
        return render_template('/Update.html',user=user)

Comment: the Upate.html is as below <h1>Welcome to Update Zone</h1>
<br>

<br>

<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('Update') }}">

CR_ID <input type="text" name="CR_ID" value = "{{user[0]}}"/>
  <br>
Name <input type="text" name="name" value = "{{user[1]}}"/>
  <br>

Email <input type="email" name="email" value = "{{user[2]}}"/>
  <br>

<input type="Submit">
</form>

Comment: encountering the below error "werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError
werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'CR_ID'"    Request your help to guide me to overcome this issue. let me know if you need any other details